# Symfony 2 - Add new article comment

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to add comments to articles with Symfony 2 but I get a white page when executing the POST.

Here is the controller :

```
public function articleAction($id)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('PortfolioPortfolioBundle:Article');
    $article = $repository->find($id);
    if($article === null)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Article[id='.$id.'] inexistant.');
    }

    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($comment)
        ->add('autor',       'text')
        ->add('content',     'textarea')
        ->getForm();

    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $article->addComment($comment);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PortfolioPortfolioBundle:Portfolio:article.html.twig', array(
    'article' => $article, "active" => "article", 'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Here is the article model :

```
public function addComment(\Portfolio\PortfolioBundle\Entity\Comment $comment)
{
    $this->comments[] = $comment;
    $comments->setArticle($this);
    return $this;
}

public function removeComment(\Portfolio\PortfolioBundle\Entity\Comment $comment)
{
    $this->comments->removeElement($comment);
}

public function getcomments()
{
    return $this->comments;
}
```

Here is the comment model :

```
<?php

namespace Portfolio\PortfolioBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Comment
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Portfolio\PortfolioBundle\Entity\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Portfolio\PortfolioBundle\Entity\Article", inversedBy="comments")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $article;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="autor", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $autor;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 */
private $content;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->date = new \Datetime('now');
}
/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set autor
 *
 * @param string $autor
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setAutor($autor)
{
    $this->autor = $autor;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get autor
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAutor()
{
    return $this->autor;
}

/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = new \DateTime("now");

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set article
 *
 * @param \Portfolio\PortfolioBundle\Entity\Article $article
 * @return Comment
 */
public function setArticle(\Portfolio\PortfolioBundle\Entity\Article $article)
{
    $this->article = $article;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get article
 *
 * @return \Portfolio\PortfolioBundle\Entity\Article 
 */
public function getArticle()
{
    return $this->article;
}
}
```

Here is the view :

```
<form class="comment-text" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
                                    <div class="controls-group col-md-10">
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <!--<textarea id="content" name="content" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment" rows="5"></textarea><br/>-->
                                            {{ form_widget(form) }}
                                            <button id="contact-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>                                             
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Logs :

```
[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
```

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []

```
[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] request.INFO: Matched route "Article" (parameters: "_controller": "Portfolio\PortfolioBundle\Controller\PortfolioController::articleAction", "id": "2", "_route": "Article") [] []

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] [

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []

[2013-11-14 10:25:36] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.title AS title2, t0.description AS description3, t0.date AS date4, t0.autor AS autor5, t0.content AS content6 FROM Article t0 WHERE t0.id = ? ["2"] []
```

Apache error log:

```
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setArticle() on a non-object in C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\src\\Portfolio\\PortfolioBundle\\Entity\\Article.php on line 206, referer: /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP Stack trace:, referer: /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\web\\app_dev.php:0, referer: /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP   2. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\web\\app_dev.php:28, referer: Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP   3. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2249, referer: /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP   4. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2947, referer: /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP   5. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleRaw() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2818, referer: Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP   6. call_user_func_array() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2844, referer: Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP   7. Portfolio\\PortfolioBundle\\Controller\\PortfolioController->articleAction() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2844, referer: Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
[Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP   8. Portfolio\\PortfolioBundle\\Entity\\Article->addComment() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\src\\Portfolio\\PortfolioBundle\\Controller\\PortfolioController.php:173, referer: Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2
```

Do you see any mistake ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: what is the problem in the app/logs/dev.logs?

Comment: Off topic: you typed `autor` instead of `author`.

Comment: Off topic again: instead of creating and returning `$array_article`, just return `$article`.

Comment: I returned $article instead of $array_article and I made a mistake everywhere inserting autor instead of author ^^'. But I still get the white page. I added the logs.

Comment: Look in your apache2 log (if you use apache2). I think it's a typo like a forgotten }

Comment: Probably this [Thu Nov 14 11:47:59 2013] [error] [client ] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setArticle() on a non-object in C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\src\\Portfolio\\PortfolioBundle\\Entity\\Article.php on line 206, referer: /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/article/2

Comment: Thank you very much guys, the error was that I put $comments->setArticle($this); instead of $comment->setArticle($this);, Next time I'll check the apache logs. Have a good day